# Is there a way to change the event handler in a javafx HTMLEditor?

Tags: java, html, events, javafx, editor

I find that when you press enter the formatting of the text gets messed up because it adds a new paragraph(`<p>`) so I was wondering if there was a way to change the enter event handler so that it only adds a line break (`<br>`)?